# Get names of games that have the highest number of guilds

Tags: mysql

I've a database which contains tables:

- *Quest*:

  ```
  PK  Name
  PK  qName
      goal
  ```
- *Guild*:

  ```
  PK  Name
  PK  gName
      level
  ```
- *Game*:

  ```
  PK  Name
      MaxPlayer
      levels
      uName
  ```
- *GuildQuest*:

  ```
  PK  Name
  PK  gName
  PK  qName
  ```

I need to retrieve the names of the games that contain the highest number of guilds.

Guilds are assigned by the game.

My attempted query:

```
SELECT Name, Count(*) guildName
FROM Game game, Guild guild 
WHERE game.Name = Guild.gName
```

and somehow use the MAX function.

I'm kind of confused how to perform this, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One obvious solution is to get all the counts, sort them in the descending order and retrieve just the topmost row:

```
SELECT
  gName,
  COUNT(Name) AS GuildCount
FROM
  Guild
GROUP BY
  gName
ORDER BY
  GuildCount DESC
LIMIT
  0, 1
;
```

That would work only in cases where only one game can have the maximum number, but you probably cannot guarantee that. So the above solution is not very good, because in cases where two or more games have the same highest number you say you want to get all those names.

So, you could try this approach instead:

```
SELECT
  gName,
  COUNT(Name) AS GuildCount
FROM
  Guild
GROUP BY
  gName
HAVING
  COUNT(Name) =
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(Name)
    FROM
      Guild
    GROUP BY
      gName
    ORDER BY
      GuildCount DESC
    LIMIT
      0, 1
  )
;
```

The subquery will get just the number, the highest guild count, and the outer query will get the names of those games that have the matching number of guilds.

The problem with the above is obviously that you have to scan the table twice, each time performing the same grouping, and the grouping itself, moreover, has to be repeated in the code as well. Question is, how to avoid that?

Now, where other SQL platforms offer powerful instruments like ranking functions, MySQL is trying to make up by allowing you to use variables to achieve better performance. In this case, too, it is possible to use variables to get the results in one go and avoid repetition of logic. Here is one way:

```
SELECT
  gName,
  GuildCount
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      IF(@LastCount <> 0 AND @LastCount <> grp.GuildCount, @flag := 0, @flag) AS flag,
      grp.gName,
      @LastCount := grp.GuildCount AS GuildCount
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          @LastCount := 0,
          @flag := 1
      ) AS init,
      (
        SELECT
          gName,
          COUNT(Name) AS GuildCount
        FROM
          Guild
        GROUP BY
          gName
        ORDER BY
          GuildCount DESC
      ) AS grp
  ) AS derived
WHERE
  flag = 1
;
```

The `init` derived table is just for variable initialisation, and `grp` provides the initial set of aggregated values sorted in the descending order to use our variables on.

The main part of the logic is located at the second nesting level where the variables are actually used. The `@flag` variable is used to generated the `flag` column for further filtering, marking rows that need to be included in the output with `1` and the rest with `0`. It is initially set to 1 because the first row obviously need to be included. It is reset to 0 as soon as the number less than the maximum is encountered. To help with that, the other variable, `@LastCount`, is used, which stores the previous row's count value.

The outermost query merely filters the nested set on the `flag` column.

This solution can be tested [at Rextester](http://rextester.com/SBMU70404).

Comment: Say `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(Name)` unless you are specifically counting the number of rows with non-NULL Names.

Comment: Check that the Optimizer did not throw out the `ORDER BY` in the subquery.

Comment: @RickJames: Not sure about the ORDER BY point but COUNT(*) and COUNT(Name) in this case would work identically because Name participates in the PK and so can't have nulls. I wasn't sure which one to go with, ended up with COUNT(Name) as potentially making more sense (as in "counting Names per gName").

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   TOP 1 gName, COUNT(Name) AS Count
FROM 
   Guild
GROUP BY
   gName
ORDER BY
   Count DESC
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50176/discussion-on-answer-by-erik-bergstedt-get-names-of-games-that-have-the-highest).